# How display alert message when live stream is unavailable?

Tags: android, stream, message, alert

I have developed live stream app but some time the live stream is unavailable 
I want to display an error or alert message when it is unavaialble
How can i do it ??

this is my create function :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){           
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shada);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);                
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));       
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        pro = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading....");
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pro.dismiss();                  
            }
        });               
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [setOnErrorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29) ?